# Clang complains "cannot override a deleted function" while no function is deleted

Tags: c++11, language-lawyer, clang++, overriding, virtual-destructor

In the following simple code fragment:

```
#include <cstddef>

struct B
{
  virtual ~B() = default;
  static void operator delete(void *, int);
  static void * operator new(size_t, int);
};

struct C : B
{
  virtual ~C() = default;
};
```

clang 3.7 complains that "non-deleted function '~C' cannot override a deleted function":
http://goo.gl/Ax6oth

Neither Visual Studio nor GCC report an error in this code. Is it a clang defect or what?

Comment: with correct signatures, it compiles

Comment: I assume that Clang is rejecting it on the basis of the third bullet point in [\[class.dtor\]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#5). I'm not quite sure whether that's the right reading.

Comment: it's right to not compile it, but the error message is less than helpful

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Probably it is right that both ~B() and ~C() are deleted. But why clang reports the error on ~C() =default only? GCC 5.2 compiles the code without any errors (both ~B() and ~C() are deleted)

Comment: Note that I got the same compiler error, but this was due to the virtual destructor not being public in my (interface) class. This comment might help the next reader landing here due to the error message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> static void operator delete(void *, int);
> ```

No, it's

```
 static void operator delete(void *, std::size_t);
```

and that type difference causes an ambiguity that gets relevant:

[cppreference.com has](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor)

> The implicitly-declared or defaulted destructor for class T is
> undefined (until C++11)defined as deleted (since C++11) if any of the
> following is true:
>
> [...]
>
> The implicitly-declared destructor is virtual (because the base class
> has a virtual destructor) and the lookup for the deallocation
> function (operator delete() results in a call to ambiguous, deleted,
> or inaccessible function.

And in the standard (draft n4140) §12.4 that is

> 5 A defaulted destructor for a class X is defined as deleted if:
>
> [...]
>
> (5.3) or, for a virtual destructor, lookup of the non-array
> deallocation function results in an ambiguity or in a function that is
> deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted destructor.

Answer (score -2):

I encountered same problem. @decltype_auto said it's a C++11 feature. So I use option "-std=c++98" to bypass the problem.